# SQLiteCursor change query

Tags: android, sqlite, memory, memory-leaks

Is is possible to change the SQL query statement of an already instantiated `SQLiteCursor`? I would like to be able to specify a given fixed `CursorWindow` to the `SQLiteCursor`, via setWindow, so that future queries get placed in the same container rather than opening new ones, but each query will be different. So the idea would be to do something like:

```
SQLiteDatabase db = openOrCreateDatabase(...);
CursorWindow cursorWindow = new CursorWindow("MyCursorWindow");
SQLiteQuery sqliteQueryObject;

//first query
String query = "SELECT * FROM Table";
sqliteQueryObject = SomeFunctionThatCreatesASQLiteQueryFromAStatement(query)
SQLiteCursor cursor = new SQLiteCursor(db, ...., sqliteQueryObject)

SQLiteCursor.setWindow(cursorWindow);

//subsequent queries
String query = "SELECT * FROM AnotherTable";
sqliteQueryObject = SomeFunctionThatCreatesASQLiteQueryFromAStatement(query)
SQLiteCursor.SomeFunctionToSetANewQuery(sqliteQueryObject);
SQLiteCursor.requery();
```

Internally the `SQLiteCursor` would have to set `private SQLiteQuery mQuery` to the new query, before executing `requery()`.